# Variable of ICollectionView Interface type

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am new to WPF and looks like I do not understand C# completely either.
The code below is supposed to provide sorted data to DataGrid.

Here is the code I struggle to understand:

```
ObservableCollection<Person> PersonsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
//this one is easy: I create new collection for objects of class Person and I call it PersonsCollection  

ICollectionView PersonsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(PersonsCollection);
//this one is more complicated. Does it mean that I create new object called PersonsView which I assume that implements ICollectionView interface?  

ListCollectionView personsView = PersonsView as ListCollectionView;  
//this one I do not understand. Why do we need it? How can we treat PersonsView as ListCollectionView?  

personsView.CustomSort = new PersonSorter();  
//here we assign object of PersonSorter class to do the sorting. Fine with me.  

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = personsView;
//and here we assign personsView as a ItemsSource for our DataGrid. Fine with me.
```

Any help?
Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this one is easy: I create new collection for objects of class Person and I call it PersonsCollection.

Correct, but I wanted to clear a few things first. You can use any collection here, or to be more precise any `IEnumerable`.

What differentiates an `ObservableCollection` from a normal `IEnumerable` is that the first one raises notifications when items are added, removed or re-ordered in the collection while the latter doesn't.

**IMPORTANT:** One thing to notice is that no matter what type of collection, whether an `IEnumerable` or an `ObservableCollection`, when that collection is used in bindings then the WPF system creates a wrapper around that collection *(source)*, sort of like a default *view*.

That view implements `ICollectionView`. It keeps notion of the current item and provides capabilities like sorting, navigation, filtering and grouping.

This view is related to the collection *(source)* so if you have multiple bindings to that same collection then all of those bindings actually bind to the default view created by the WPF system so they are updated together when the default view is updated.

I had to clear that last important topic because it relates to the questions ahead.

> this one is more complicated. Does it mean that I create new object called PersonsView which I assume that implements `ICollectionView` interface ?

No or at least not entirely true. You you are getting the reference to that default view that will be created by the WPF system, that's why the method to obtain that object is called `GetDefaultView()` and not something like `CreateDefaultView()`.

> this one I do not understand. Why do we need it? How can we treat PersonsView as ListCollectionView?

We don't really need it, we can go without this line. We can treat `PersonView` as a `ListCollectionView` because

> all collections have a default CollectionView. For all collections
> implementing IList, the ListCollectionView object is the default view
> object.

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx).

The rest of it is the fine with you and fine by me so no need to comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my understanding:

Your first line:

```
ObservableCollection<Person> PersonsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

As you rightly say, is creating your observable collection of `Persons`, you could bind directly to this collection (technically I believe you bind to the default `CollectionView`), and your `DataGrid` would be notified of changes to the collection, and update accordingly. But you want the additional feature of sorting the data.

So, your second line:

```
ICollectionView PersonsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(PersonsCollection);
```

Is using the `GetDefaultView` to return the default `CollectionView` for your `PersonsCollection`, a `CollectionView` is a wrapper around your existing collection, that will give you additional behaviours, like filtering, grouping, navigating, and **sorting**. When a collection is bound in WPF, the binding is to a `CollectionView` object, and it is these views which are manipulated when the data is sorted and displayed, etc.

It happens to be the case, that the default type of `CollectionViewSource` for this type, is a `ListCollectionView`, but since this may vary depending on what type of object you pass to `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView()`, the method returns an interface, `ICollectionView`.

So at this point, we could use the `ICollectionView`, `PersonsView` as the `ItemsSource`, but we want to define custom sorting behaviour, by defining a `CustomSort`, which can be found on a `ListCollectionView`.

Since we know that the default view is a `ListCollectionView`, we can explicitly cast the `ICollectionView` object accordingly (3rd line), and then set the desired sorting behaviour (4th line):

```
ListCollectionView personsView = PersonsView as ListCollectionView;  

personsView.CustomSort = new PersonSorter();
```

Hopefully some more knowledgeable users will point out any mistakes I've made.

Comment: ICollectionView is allowed to be ItemsSource? But it is an Interface not a collection so how does it work?

Comment: You can't instantiate an interface directly, so the object returned will be a concrete class which implements `ICollectionView`, if you interrogate the type returned you'll find it's a `ListCollectionView`. An `ICollectionView` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so this type must implement `IEnumerable`. If you have a look at the `ItemsSource` property, it is of type `IEnumerable`, so you could happily bind to any type which implements the `ICollectionView` (as that implies it must implement `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection you are creating an ObservableCollection which is used to fire the CollectionChanged event on that is change DP value.
ICollectionView you are creating view from the person collection that will be used to display the collection data in WPF datagrid etc.
 
ListCollectionview smilar to ICollectionView but you can sort or filters the itmes etc.

```
 personsView.CustomSort = new PersonSorter();  // depending on which Tech you are using for example it might be you are creating the sorting property Name.
```